# struts2 actions - Multiple Methods & Multiple classes

Tags: java, struts2

How do you create an action in struts2 that uses multiple methods in different classes?

So for example I would like something like this but I'm pretty sure this doesn't work:

```
<action name="person_create" method="personCreate, carCreate" class="PersonActionBean, CarActionBean">
   <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

To be specific, I'm using struts 2.1.8.1

**PersonAction.java** - **personCreate()**:

`Person person = new Person();`

**CarAction.java** - **carCreate()**:

`Car car = new Car();`

Comment: can you be more clear about your requirements as what you mean by multiple methods?

Comment: Please see edit. On my jsp I need to initialise 2 objects. The `Car` and `Person` objects.

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd create the objects in a single action.

Comment: The problem is that there are 2 forms. So the one form goes to `Car_Save` and the other goes to `Person_Save` (Which use `CarAction` and `PersonAction` respectively). If I initialise the `Car` and `Person` object in just 1 of the actions like you say then one of the saves won't work because the objects won't be initialised in both Actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two variable:

**1**: why are you willing to call 2 actions, from the concept of MVC, you shouldn't do this, if you wanna process to different objects, you should build a new layer(e.g. interface, or service layer) to do this.

**2**: if you have to do this, you can define a new action, which using the `chain` result type to call them all. here is the [Chain result type](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/chain-result.html), but be careful.

Comment: The problem is that there are 2 forms. So the one form goes to `Car_Save` and the other goes to `Person_Save` (Which use `CarAction` and `PersonAction` respectively. If I initialise the `Car` and `Person` object in just 1 of the actions like you say then one of the saves won't work because the objects won't be initialised in both Actions. Each action has its own layers, so `PersonAction`, `PersonService`,`PersonDao`, etc all make up the `Person` layer. If I try to move all the `Car` functionality inside `Person` then things will begin to get really messy.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you clearly you want to call 2 action classes when call persone_create action.
And can you show me this action classes.
If this classes having fields with the same name it will be a problem.
Because all field from action classes (when action class is called) go to the ValueStack and in result only one of this classes will be having all fields with information from your jsp page.

Comment: I think ypu make a mistake when creating your app. We creating Action classes for each kind of request(not always).. And I sea that you make Action element for yours entites classes. It is a mistake.. I think you need change your Action classes or make one class wich contains persone and car objects

Comment: I can't because on the jsp page there are 2 forms. One that saves person and one that saves car. This requires 2 separate Actions which means 2 separate Service, Dao, Domain, etc.

Comment: I think you submit each form with personal button(each form have submit button)

Comment: so you can make 2 actions in struts.xml

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it doesn't work that way.  Consider if one action returned success and another action returned error.  Which result would the struts2 framework execute in that case?

Instead what you can do is call one action method that will call the other two methods within it.  Something like this:

```
<action name="person_create" method="execute" class="MainAction">
   <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

And as part of that action, you can call your other methods, like:

```
public String execute() {
    Person person = new Person();
    Car car = new Car();
    // Add any additional logic and return appropriate value
}
```

If the above isn't an appropriate solution, please edit your question with more details as to why you want to call two separate methods in your action.  It is still unclear to me why you would want the two methods for one action in that way.

Comment: The problem is that there are 2 forms. So the one form goes to `Car_Save` and the other goes to `Person_Save` (Which use `CarAction` and `PersonAction` respectively). If I initialise the `Car` and `Person` object in just 1 of the actions like you say then one of the saves won't work because the objects won't be initialised in both Actions.

Answer (score 1):

or you can make something like this

```
public class MainAction extends ActionSupport{

private Car car;
private Persone persone;

public String execute() {
 }

// add getters and setters to car and persone objects.
}
```

And your jsp will be look like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="init">
    <s:textfield key="car.name" name="car.name"/>
    <s:textfield key="car.year" name="car.year"/>
    <s:textfield key="car.name" name="car.name"/>
    <s:textfield key="car.year" name="car.year"/></s:textarea>
    <s:submit key="init.submit"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and your struts.xml file:

```
<action name="init" method="execute" class="MainAction">
   <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and when you submit form  your action class will be contain persone and car objects with info from form))

Comment: Each action has its own layers, so `PersonAction`, `PersonService`,`PersonDao`, etc all make up the `Person` layer. If I try to move all the `Car` functionality inside `Person` then things will begin to get really messy.

Comment: are you using some IoC container? cannot you declare `CarService` in your `PersonAction` ?

Comment: Yes I can. I decided to take that route after all despite my unwillingness :)